# About oracle oam middleware login page

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, oam

In my project, I used Oracle SSO, I want to use a custom login page to replace the login page with the system in oracle oam.
But, I don't know how to replace login page.

If any of you know anything, give advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try ? Have you gone through the Oracle documentation ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/dev.1112/e27134/custpages.htm#AIDEV350

Answer (score 0):

I have a link which shows the custom Login page in Oracle Access Management (OAM); here is the [Link](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/external-custom-login-forms-with-oracle-access-manager-11g/)

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  It's preferable to also include a brief summary, rather than just a link. Then the answer will still be useful to others, even if the link breaks or changes.